# Error while running maven command in gcp console unable to install common package error

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-shell

**unable to install apache maven packages in gcp console please let me know if any one resolves the issue. I'm trying to create dataflow pipeline following the below link**
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kafka-to-bigquery-using-dataflow-6ec73ec249bb)

```
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  51.368 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-30T15:27:29Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.2:compile (default-compile) on project common: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/prasanna_kumar/DataflowTemplates/v2/common/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/utils/CacheUtils.java:[78,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DataStreamClient
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.utils.CacheUtils.DataStreamPkCache
[ERROR] /home/prasanna_kumar/DataflowTemplates/v2/common/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/utils/CacheUtils.java:[80,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DataStreamClient
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.utils.CacheUtils.DataStreamPkCache
[ERROR] /home/prasanna_kumar/DataflowTemplates/v2/common/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/cdc/mappers/MergeInfoMapper.java:[29,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DataStreamClient
[ERROR]   location: package com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.utils
[ERROR] /home/prasanna_kumar/DataflowTemplates/v2/common/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/cdc/mappers/MergeInfoMapper.java:[59,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DataStreamClient
[ERROR]   location: class com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.cdc.mappers.MergeInfoMapper
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :common
```

Comment: `Compilation failure: Compilation failure:` - check corresponding source codes.

Comment: which part or file should I check? I'm new to java and these packages.

Comment: Look at the error log. It says which classes it cannot compile. It's either a compile time errors, or something which your java compiler (inappropriate version) cannot compile.

Comment: Besides, if you are new to Java (or, to programming, in general), I would really suggest you start with something relatively easier, than Kafka Streams.

Comment: Do you only use Dataflow through BigQuery?

Comment: Did you follow this [guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/v2/kafka-to-bigquery) compiling the sources?

Comment: No I followed a medium blog post I've attached in the question. I tried java doc samples  on kafka to bigquery. It worked well but I'm getting the above error when I follow the blog post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now this is well known to developers bug, confirmed on my side, getting the same  `kafka-to-bigquery` template compilation error around `DataStreamClient` class. Seems the new PR for `CacheUtils.java` is going to appear soon, more info [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/commit/9f1cc812d2175bc3986e78d0deda8174db5c34b6#r41864843).

Comment: Thanks nick will check it out. Do you have any other post or reference for Kafka to bigquery

Comment: It will be worth to try Google predefined [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#running-the-apache-kafka-to-bigquery-template). If you find the answer was helpful consider perform [accept/up vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) action as essential part of community collaboration model.